# How to connect multiple consecutive views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, view, swiftui

I am working on an app which allows users to create their own flashcards. These flash cards will be then shown on a list view with a search bar as below:

```
List {
                        ForEach(results.filter({text.isEmpty ? true :$0.subject?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(text) as! Bool}), id: \.self) { (retrievedFlashCard: FlashCard) in
                            ZStack{
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/3.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5)
                            HStack {
                                Text(retrievedFlashCard.flashcard ?? "No Name").bold().lineLimit(4)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .padding()
                                Spacer()
                                Text(retrievedFlashCard.subject ?? "No Subject").foregroundColor(.red)
                                    .italic()
                                    .padding()
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedFlashCard = retrievedFlashCard
                            }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                    }
                }
```

Is there any way the users can launch multiple selected flashcards which are going to show one after the other by tapping a next button on each view?
Hope that is clear.

Comment: Not too clear to me. Sounds like maybe when it is tapped. You want to store the index so that it can be increments later on the subsequent views to find out which card to show? Or are you asking how to select multiple items from a list?

Comment: Yeah sorry I am just starting to code so I'm not really familiar with the correct terminology. I want users to select the flashcards they want to revise (which I know how to do) and then show them in another view one at time by tapping a button

Comment: Every time a user selects a Flashcard for revision, you would append that flashcard to an array of flashcards. Once the selection is completed you would pass this array to the new view for processing in what ever manner you want

Comment: Yes exactly. Could you please show me an example of code to append selected flashcards to an array which is integrable in my list view?